# Google-TV: SoundPool: Unable to load sample: (null)

Tags: android, audio, google-tv

It works on Motorola Xoom tablet 3.2.1 but doesn't works on google-tv Logitech Revue 3.2

```
SoundPool soundPool = new SoundPool(16, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
poolId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.cat, 1);
soundPool.play(poolId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0, 1);
```

Such log error: SoundPool: Unable to load sample: (null).

Any ideas would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SoundPool class on GoogleTV will not load MP3 tracks. Use OGG instead